# Global Jquery code not working in a loaded file

Tags: jquery

I've got a file called 'nav.js', and in that file, I check for clicks on links, and load the corresponding page. The problem is, when I load a file with this code, and for example have a "a href="#test"" in the loaded file, it doesn't execute the 'nav' code. The problem is, when I include this file in the loaded file, when I click a link, the code is executed twice, or sometimes tens of times.

Nav.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    $('a').click(function() {
        var filename = $(this).attr('href');
        var clickable = $(this).attr('clickable');

        if(clickable === "no") {

        } else {
            if(filename === null) {

            } else {
                filename = filename.substring(1, filename.length);

                var attributes = "";
                if (~filename.indexOf("?")) {
                    attributes = "?" + filename.split('?')[1];
                    filename = filename.split('?')[0];
                }

                $('.maincontainer').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $('.loader').fadeIn('fast');
                    $(".ms-footer").css("position", "fixed"); 
                    $(".maincontainer").load("../phppages/" + filename + ".php" + attributes, 
                        function(responseText, textStatus) {
                            history.pushState('', 'Politie Amsterdam | Website', "#"+filename+"&"+attributes+"");

                            $('.maincontainer').fadeIn();
                            $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');

                            if (textStatus === "error") {
                                $(".maincontainer").load("../phppages/404.php");
                            }
                        });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me to fix this.

EDIT 2:

```
     <div class="maincontainer">
     <?php if(isset($_GET[home]) OR empty($_GET)) {
                require("phppages/mainhome.php");
            } 
     ?>
   </div>
     <footer class="ms-footer">
        <div class="container">
           <p>&copy; Politie Amsterdam | Habbo | <?php echo date(Y); ?> | Wij zijn op geen enkele manier verbonden met Sulake en/of de Amsterdamse Politie. <br> Coding by: xxtristan19051 | Bedankt  aan: Stefano191 & Thisse</p>
        </div>
     </footer>
     <div class="btn-back-top">
        <a href="#" clickable="no" data-scroll id="back-top" class="btn-circle btn-circle-primary btn-circle-sm btn-circle-raised ">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-up"></i>
        </a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- sb-site-container -->
  <?php require("modules/sidenav.php"); ?>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/nav.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show how you include your "nav.js" in your HTML document? 

It's recommended that you include this script after you load all your HTML elements or in other words include your "nav.js" in footer.

Comment: Putting this code in your loaded HTML, will cause multiple event being bind to element. So if "nav.js" is loaded every time an HTML is loaded to your current HTML, for example 3 times, then it will cause 3 click events to bind.

Comment: replace `$('a').click(function(){` to `$(document).off("click", "a").on("click", "a", function() { `

Comment: @Philip Borbon I know this. It was my try for a temp solution, but it didn't work sadly enough. Still thanks for the reaction! :)

Comment: where did you link jquery??

Comment: Jquery is linked at the top of the page, and that works fine. ;) @Kathara

Comment: aaah ok. I thought it was missing ;)

Comment: why don't you use $("#back-top") instead of $("a")?